# Unit testing code that references Rails models without loading the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to unit test a Plain Old Ruby Object that has a method which calls a class method on a Rails model. The Rails app is quite large (10s of seconds to load) so I'd prefer to avoid loading all of Rails to do my unit test which should run in under 1s.

Example:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    SomeRailsModel.quxo(3)
  end
end

RSpec.describe Foo do
  let(:instance) { Foo.new }

  it 'calls quxo on SomeRailsModel' do
    expect(SomeRailsModel).to receive(:quxo)
    instance.bar
  end
end
```

The problem here is that I need to `require 'rails_helper'` to load up Rails in order for `app/models/some_rails_model` to be available. This leads to slow unit tests due to Rails dependency.

I've tried defining the constant locally and then using regular `spec_helper` which kind of works.

Example:

```
RSpec.describe Foo do
  let(:instance) { Foo.new }
  SomeRailsModel = Object.new unless Kernel.const_defined?(:SomeRailsModel)

  it 'calls quxo on SomeRailsModel' do
    expect(SomeRailsModel).to receive(:quxo)
    instance.bar
  end
end
```

This code lets me avoid loading all of Rails and executes very fast. Unfortunately, by default (and I like this) RSpec treats the constant as a partial double and complains that my `SomeRailsModel` constant doesn't respond to the `quxo` message. Verifying doubles are nice and I'd like to keep that safety harness. I can individually disable the verification by wrapping it in a special block defined by RSpec.

Finally, the question. What is the recommended way to have fast unit tests on POROs that use Rails models without requiring all of Rails while also keeping verifying doubles functionality enabled? Is there a way to create a "slim" `rails_helper` that can just load `app/models` and the minimal subset of `ActiveRecord` to make the verification work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After noodling a few ideas with colleagues, here is the concensus solution:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    SomeRailsModel.quxo(3)
  end
end

require 'spec_helper' # all we need!

RSpec.describe Foo do
  let(:instance) { Foo.new }
  let(:stubbed_model) do
    unless Kernel.const_defined?("::SomeRailsModel")
      Class.new { def self.quxo(*); end }
    else
      SomeRailsModel
    end
  end

  before { stub_const("SomeRailsModel", stubbed_model) }

  it 'calls quxo on SomeRailsModel' do
    expect(stubbed_model).to receive(:quxo)
    instance.bar
  end
end
```

When run locally, we'll check to see if the model class has already been defined. If it has, *use it* since we've already paid the price to load that file. If it isn't, then create an anonymous class that implements the interface under test. Use `stub_const` to stub in either the anonymous class or the real deal.

For local tests, this will be very fast. For tests run on a CI server, we'll detect that the model was already loaded and preferentially use it. We get automatic double method verification too in all cases.

If the real Rails model interface changes but the anonymous class falls behind, a CI run will catch it (or an integration test will catch it).

UPDATE:
We will probably DRY this up a bit with a helper method in spec_helper.rb. Such as:

```
def model_const_stub(name, &blk)
  klass = unless Kernel.const_defined?('::' + name.to_s)
            Class.new(&blk)
          else
            Kernel.const_get(name.to_s)
          end

  stub_const(name.to_s, klass)
  klass
end

# DRYer!
let(:model) do
  model_const_stub('SomeRailsModel') do
    def self.quxo(*); end
  end
end
```

Probably not the final version but this gives a flavor of our direction.